# Do not understand the duality given by the non-degenerate bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, direct-product

I have a difficulty when reading "Lectures in Abstract Algebra, II. Linear Algebra" by Nathan Jacobson (GTM #31). The section is excerpted at the end of the question. The sentence I have difficulty is underlined with red. My problem is: the definition of a bilinear form should be given based on a left and a right vector space, i.e., we first have the left vector space $\mathfrak{R}$ then we have the bilinear form $g$. But here the author was using a bilinear form to define a left vector space $\mathfrak{R}$, and the introduction of the bilinear form has already used the $\mathfrak{R}$ as part of its definition which the book is trying to define. Such a circular definition confused me and therefor I ask here. What on earth are $\mathfrak{R}$ and the bilinear form $g$? What is the relation between them? Please try to use the notation and concept before that section in the text. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This text is a slightly difficult to follow, but I think it's quite unambiguous. The first paragraph is basically saying "You already know what a bilinear form is. In this chapter, we'll define a similar idea, a product group". The second paragraph actually defines what a product group is. That's the heart. The third paragraph says, "Hey, you already know some product groups! A non-zero bilinear form is a product group iff its value ring $\Delta$ is commutative." The fourth paragraph says, "You can actually construct a product group for any two vector spaces $\mathfrak{R}'$ and $\mathfrak{S}$. We'll show you how."

That fourth paragraph is not *defining* a product group. It’s showing how to construct a product group, given vector spaces $\mathfrak{R}$, $\mathfrak{R}'$, and $\mathfrak{S}$ and a bilinear form $g:\mathfrak{R}\times\mathfrak{R}'\to\Delta$. The phrase, “$\mathfrak{R}$ dual to $\mathfrak{R}’$”, just means there’s a bilinear form $g(x,y’)$ for $x\in\mathfrak{R}$ and $y’\in\mathfrak{R}’$. By choosing different $\mathfrak{R}$ and $g()$, you'll get different product groups for the same $\mathfrak{R}'$ and $\mathfrak{S}$.

The author said, "We shall give next a way of forming a product group for any pair of vector spaces $\mathfrak{R}'$ and $\mathfrak{S}$". What's perhaps confusing you is that this construction doesn't only depend on $\mathfrak{R}'$ and $\mathfrak{S}.$ It also depends on $\mathfrak{R}$ and $g()$. The author just slips those into the discussion, seemingly out of nowhere. But such a dual space $\mathfrak{R}$ always exists and there's always a corresponding bilinear form $g()$ expressing this duality. (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space).) So all is well.

Comment: I have no difficulty in understanding the first three paragraphs (I include them just to avoid different notations and definitions), and I know what the 4th paragraph is trying to do (my question is only the red lines). But I can't catch you because, to speak frankly, I don't agree with you. As the text says, the dual space is determined by the bilinear form. But my understanding is that, without first giving a left vector space R, a bilinear form cannot be given because R is part of g. I have already (clearly) spelled out this circular dependency, and this is exactly what I am asking.

Comment: PS, I have already read the wiki before posting this question but the wiki only make me more confused. The last sentence of your answer seems to be the question I am asking. Is "dual space" mean "conjugate space" which is the collection of all linear functions (of R')? What is the "corresponding bilinear form expressing this duality" you mentioned in this sentence? Could you please expand on it?

Comment: "The dual space is determined by the bilinear form"? Where does it say that? I'm not even sure that it would mean necessarily. And I'm sorry for your frustration. It is not easy debugging someone else's thought processes.

Comment: The confusion may come in part from the fact that most authors describe "the" dual space of a vector space to be *the* space of linear functionals on that vector space. If $V$ is a vector space and $V^*$ is its space of linear functionals, then $g(v,v')= v'(v)$ is a bilinear form ($v\in V$, $v'\in V^*$). This author uses the language "... this duality is given by the non-degenerate bi-linear form...", and that's the associated bi-linear form he has in mind. However, he talks about "*a* space dual to $\mathfrak{R}'$".

Comment: He probably defined *a* dual vector space in a previous chapter and discussed associated bilinear forms. This will clarify what he means by "this duality is given by the non-degenerate bi-linear form".

Comment: I just saw your comment asking for clarification on my last sentence. The author of the text you're quoting is using a slightly different definition of "dual vector space" than the one I've seen most often (the set of linear functionals). That's the one used on the Wikiepedia page. This author uses the phrase "*a* dual space", which suggests he's using a different definition. But it doesn't really matter. All that's necessary is that $g$ is a bilinear form on $\mathfrak{R}$ and $\mathfrak{R}'$. Don't get caught up in the terminology there. There is no circularity.

Answer (score 0):

It might be clearer to state the construction as follows.

We are given a right vector space $R'$ and left vector space $S$, over the field $F$.

Take *any* vector space $R$ over $F$ of the same dimension as $R'$.  Take a non-degenerate bilinear form $g : R \times R' \to F$.  Then we may define a map $g : R' \times S \to L(R, S)$ by $$g(x', y)(x) = g(x, x')(y)$$ where $x \in R, x' \in R', y \in S$.

Does this help?